# Adicionando a função editar em um único Form no AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou começando a ter contato com o AngularJS e desenvolvi uma aplicação simples de cadastro, onde posso inserir e deletar dados. Mas estou com dificuldades para implementar a função de editar.

Estou usando apenas um Form e estou tentando manter a função de editar usando este mesmo form. Mas ainda não consegui fazer funcionar corretamente. Segue abaixo os códigos que fiz com a última alteração para a função editar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="cadastro">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>BonilhaTech - Cadastro de Usuários</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .usuario-conteudo {
            background-color: #EEE;
            padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <div class="usuario-conteudo" ng-controller="UsuarioController">
                <div class="boasvindas" >
                    <h1 style="text-align: center"> {{myHeader}} </h1>
                </div>                
                <h1>Cadastro de Usuários</h1>
                <form name="formulario" ng-if="update">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nome">Nome*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Nome do usuário" 
                               maxlength="20" required ng-model="usuario.nome">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback {{statusSenha.classe}}">
                        <label for="senha">Senha*</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" placeholder="Informe a senha do Usuário" 
                               maxlength="10" required ng-model="usuario.senha" ng-change="validarSenha()">
                        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback {{statusSenha.icone}}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <p class="help-block">{{statusSenha.mensagem}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-edit">
                        <label for="nome">Para editar os dados, utilizar os campos abaixo:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Altere o nome do usuário" maxlength="20" 
                               required ng-model="update.name">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" required ng-model="update.senha"placeholder="Altere a senha do Usuário"
                               maxlength="10" ng-change="validarSenha()">
                        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback {{statusSenha.icone}}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <p class="help-block">{{statusSenha.mensagem}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-submit="cadastrar()">Cadastrar</button>
                    <button ng-click="salvar()" ng-submit="salvar()" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>
                </form>
                <hr>
                <h1>Lista de Usuários: </h1>
                <table class="table table-striped" ng-hide="UsuarioController.usuarios == 0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Senha</th>
                        <th>Ação</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <!-- Aqui serão exibidos os dados do usuários cadastrados -->
                        <tr ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios">
                            <td>{{usuario.nome}}</td>
                            <td>{{usuario.senha}}</td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="remover($index)">Remover</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Código JavaScript do Controller:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('cadastro', [])

.controller('UsuarioController', function($scope, $timeout) {

    //mensagem de Boas-Vindas
    $scope.myHeader = "BemVindo!";
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.myHeader = "Welcome!";
    }, 5000);
    // lista de usuários pré cadastrados
    $scope.usuarios = [
        { nome: 'Guerra', senha: '1234' },
        { nome: 'Jô', senha: '12345' },
        { nome: 'Pratto', senha: '12345678' },
        { nome: 'Ricardo Oliveira', senha: '1234' }
    ];

    //inicialização de um usuário vazio
    $scope.usuario = { nome: '', senha: '' };

    //método para adicionar o usuário a lista
    $scope.cadastrar = function() {
        $scope.usuarios.push($scope.usuario);
        $scope.usuario = { nome: '', senha: '' };
    };

    //método para remover o usuário da lista
    $scope.remover = function(index) {
        $scope.usuarios.splice(index, 1);
    };
    //método para validar a senha do usuário
    $scope.validarSenha = function() {
        $scope.statusSenha = {
            classe: '',
            icone: '',
            mensagem: ''
        };

        if ($scope.usuario.senha && $scope.usuario.senha.length >= 8) {
            $scope.statusSenha.classe = 'has-success';
            $scope.statusSenha.icone = 'glyphicon-ok';
            $scope.statusSenha.mensagem = 'Esta senha é forte, parabéns cabaço!';
        } else {
            $scope.statusSenha.classe = 'has-error';
            $scope.statusSenha.icone = 'glyphicon-remove';
            $scope.statusSenha.mensagem = 'Faça um favor a si mesmo, apaga isso e tente novamente.';
        }
    };
    //método para salvar e editar o nome e senha do usuário
    $scope.editar = function(user, i) {
        $scope.update = angular.copy(user);
        index = i;
    }
    $scope.salvar = function() {
        $scope.users[index] = $scope.update; 
        $scope.update = ""; 
    }
});

});

})();
```

Comment: Não consegue fazer o quê?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo fazer o editar funcionar neste cadastro. Vi alternativas mas que utilizam outro form ou mesmo gerando uma nova página html. Estou tentando fazer em uma só.

Comment: Tá bem difícil de entender qual é a sua dificuldade, João. Especificamente o que está dando errado?

Comment: Boa Noite JBueno, o problema é que a função editar não está funcionando, apenas a função cadastrar ou remover. Procurei outras maneiras de fazer a edição no mesmo form mas não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

João, fiz algumas adaptações em seu código e parece que agora está funcionando a contento. Recomendo que estude mais o AngularJS e toda sua parte de validações, pois o que você fez pode ser melhorado.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xqTlJq3c6XGDpwDBKY6x?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="cadastro">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>BonilhaTech - Cadastro de Usuários</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .usuario-conteudo {
            background-color: #EEE;
            padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <div class="usuario-conteudo" ng-controller="UsuarioController as ctrl">
                <div class="boasvindas" >
                    <h1 style="text-align: center"> {{myHeader}} </h1>
                </div>                
                <h1>Cadastro de Usuários</h1>
                <form name="formUsuario" ng-if="usuario" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nome">Nome*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Nome do usuário" 
                               maxlength="20" required ng-model="usuario.nome">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback {{statusSenha.classe}}">
                        <label for="senha">Senha*</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" placeholder="Informe a senha do Usuário" 
                               maxlength="10" required ng-model="usuario.senha" ng-change="validarSenha()">
                        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback {{statusSenha.icone}}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <p class="help-block">{{statusSenha.mensagem}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <button ng-click="cancelar()" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>
                    <button ng-click="salvar(usuario)" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                </form>
                <hr/>
                <h1>Lista de Usuários: </h1>
                <table class="table table-striped" ng-hide="usuarios.length === 0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Senha</th>
                        <th>Ação</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <!-- Aqui serão exibidos os dados do usuários cadastrados -->
                        <tr ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios">
                            <td>{{usuario.nome}}</td>
                            <td>{{usuario.senha}}</td>
                            <td>
                              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="editar(usuario)">Editar</button>
                              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="remover(usuario)">Remover</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cadastrar()">Cadastrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('cadastro', [])
  .controller('UsuarioController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    //mensagem de Boas-Vindas
    $scope.myHeader = "BemVindo!";
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.myHeader = "Welcome!";
    }, 5000);

    // lista de usuários pré cadastrados
    $scope.usuarios = [
        { id: 1, nome: 'Guerra', senha: '1234' },
        { id: 2, nome: 'Jô', senha: '12345' },
        { id: 3, nome: 'Pratto', senha: '12345678' },
        { id: 4, nome: 'Ricardo Oliveira', senha: '1234' }
    ];

    //inicialização de um usuário vazio
    $scope.usuario = null;

    //método para 
    $scope.cadastrar = function() {
      var maxId = Math.max.apply(Math, $scope.usuarios.map(function(u) { return u.id; }));
      $scope.usuario = { id: ++maxId, nome: '', senha: '' };
    };

    //método para remover o usuário da lista
    $scope.remover = function(usuario) {
      var index = $scope.usuarios.map(function(u) { return u.id; }).indexOf(usuario.id);
      $scope.usuarios.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.cancelar = function() {
      $scope.usuario = null;
    };

    //método para validar a senha do usuário
    $scope.validarSenha = function() {
        limpaStatusSenha();

        if ($scope.usuario.senha && $scope.usuario.senha.length >= 8) {
            $scope.statusSenha.classe = 'has-success';
            $scope.statusSenha.icone = 'glyphicon-ok';
            $scope.statusSenha.mensagem = 'Esta senha é forte, parabéns cabaço!';
        } else {
            $scope.statusSenha.classe = 'has-error';
            $scope.statusSenha.icone = 'glyphicon-remove';
            $scope.statusSenha.mensagem = 'Faça um favor a si mesmo, apaga isso e tente novamente.';
        }
    };
    //método para editar o usuário
    $scope.editar = function(usuario) {
      $scope.usuario = angular.copy(usuario);
      $scope.validarSenha();
    }

    $scope.salvar = function(usuario) {
      var indexAtualizado = $scope.usuarios.map(function(u) { return u.id; }).indexOf(usuario.id);
      if (indexAtualizado < 0) {
        $scope.usuarios.push(usuario);
      } else {
        $scope.usuarios[indexAtualizado] = usuario; 
      }
      $scope.usuario = null;
      limpaStatusSenha();
    }

    function limpaStatusSenha() {
      $scope.statusSenha = {
          classe: '',
          icone: '',
          mensagem: ''
      };
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: Obrigado Waldir, irei fazer os ajustes no meu código. Estou estudando a pouco tempo AngularJS e estou gostando bastante de seus recursos. Vou rever esta parte de validação pois posso ter deixado passar algo.

Comment: Ok. Lembre-se de marcar a resposta como válida, se a mesma lhe ajudou.